# How do I get machine name by entity type and its ID?

Tags: 8, entities

How do I get machine name by entity type and its ID?

The code I am using is the following.

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(2);
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->
getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the type and id of a given entity, you can do:

```
$type = $entity->bundle();
$id = $entity->id();
```

Some entities, like Node, provide wrapper methods to return the bundle:

`$type = $node->getType();`

But Block doesn't. So if it is Block that you are after:

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load(2);
$type = $block->bundle();
$id = $block->id();
```